# Trying to scrape data from a table without class or id using python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/hyday.pl?game=fd. But the code below does not give me any answer. I think something is wrong with the table path or the xpath for the name variable. Could someone please help to identify the problem?

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from kevin.items import RotoguruItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector, HtmlXPathSelector


class RotoguruSpider(CrawlSpider):

   name = 'rotoguru1'
   allowed_domains = ['rotoguru1.com']
   start_urls = ['http://rotoguru1.com/cgi-bin/hyday.pl?']
   rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['mon=\d+&day=\d+&game=fd']), callback='parse_item')]


   def parse_item(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       tablepath= '//table[@cellspacing="5"]/tbody//tr[position()>2]'
       rows = hxs.select(tablepath)
       items = []

       for row in rows:
          item = RotoguruItem()
          item['name'] = row.select("td[2]/a/text()").extract()
          items.append(item)
       return items
```

The output for the above codes is

```
H:\SourceDir\basketball>scrapy crawl rotoguru1 -o fd.csv
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: basketball)
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE'
: 'basketball.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['basketball.spi
ders'], 'FEED_URI': 'fd.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'basketball'}
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogSta
ts, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuth
Middleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, Def
aultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, Redirec
tMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMid
dleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddlew
are
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [rotoguru1] INFO: Spider opened
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [rotoguru1] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scr
aped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6
023
2015-03-19 18:52:40+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080

2015-03-19 18:52:41+0530 [rotoguru1] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://rotoguru1.
com/cgi-bin/hyday.pl?game=fd> (referer: None)
2015-03-19 18:52:41+0530 [rotoguru1] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-03-19 18:52:41+0530 [rotoguru1] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 236,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 17052,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 13, 22, 41, 513000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 13, 22, 40, 296000)}
2015-03-19 18:52:41+0530 [rotoguru1] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I need to extract the data from the table. For starters I want the array of names listed below a generated by firebug:
$x('//html//body//table//tbody//tr//td[3]//p[5]//table//tbody//tr/td[2]/a/text()')
[<TextNode textContent="Westbrook, Russell">, <TextNode textContent="Paul, Chris">, <TextNode textContent="Smart, Marcus">.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1) The URL for start_urls isn't using `game=fd`, but the LinkExtractor is expecting `game=fd` on its URLs.

2) The XPath used for table is using `tbody`, but this is not available in the HTML source parsed by Scrapy (even though this XPath expression works in the browser, because the browser adds tbody automatically).

Adding `game=fd` in start_urls, make the tablepath like `//table[@cellspacing="5"]//tr[position()>2]` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you... I used SgmlLinkExtractor and Selenium package and the scraping worked. However I had to still do the changes you had mentioned, so thank you once again...